# Is there any way to user input the folder path for the hyperlink to work properly?

Tags: arcpy, hyperlink, geotag, html-popup

So i have some geottagged photos and ive converted them to photos using the geotag photos to point tool. The hyperlink is also working as in the case the picture opens up when i click on the point.
Anyways, the problem im facing is , when im moving this photo_to_point shp to another computer( along with gdb) , the hyperlink doesnt work. I found out the reason too ( the path created in attributes isnt in the other computer storage).

What can i do to fix this?

Is there any option to edit the hyperlink tool such that when i click the point and it cant find the image file, it asks for the folder path where the image is stored?

Comment: Surely can.  If you can store the photos relative to the MXD correctly that would be a great help, then you can use os.path.join(os.path.dirname(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT').filePath), r'rest\of\path') as your origin and it doesn't matter where you put the data as long as it is relative to the MXD when it is opened. Another way to do this is to build a list of the files and store in a user location then use said list to redirect the hyperlink, this method isn't optimal as it requires users to keep their lists up to date. What's in your hyperlink code now?

Comment: As for the asking, you'd need a 3rd party lib like PyWin32 to pop up a dialog box then store the path as a system variable (don't panic, it's only valid within that one applications' instance, you shouldn't have I.T. support getting angry at you) then in your hyperlink code you can look for the environment variable and use that value if not found (os.environ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-environ-object/ for more) question methods like raw_input don't work inside an ArcMap session.